# PostgreSQL empty list VALUES expression

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to take a list of points, and query a geospatial database, to find all matching rows.

I have a computed SQL statement that looks like this:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(
    '''
    SELECT g.ident
    FROM (VALUES %s) AS v (lon, lat)
    LEFT JOIN customers g
    ON (ST_Within(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(v.lon, v.lat), %s), g.poly_home));
    ''', [AsIs(formatted_points), SRID]
)
```

Here is an example of what the formatted_points variable looks like:

```
(-115.062,38.485), (-96.295,43.771)
```

So, when that is inserted into the SQL expression, then VALUES expression reads:

```
(VALUES (-115.062,38.485), (-96.295,43.771)) AS v (lon, lat)
```

So far so good. However, when the list of points is empty, the VALUES expression looks like this:

```
(VALUES ) AS v (lon, lat)
```

.. which causes me to get this error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ")"
```

In other words, `(VALUES )` is not legal SQL.

Here's the question: How do I represent an empty list using VALUES? I could special case this, and just return an empty list when this function is passed an empty list, but that doesn't seem very elegant.

I have looked at the [PostgreSQL manual page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-values.html) for VALUES, but I don't understand how to construct an empty VALUES expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can put your lons and lats in separate arrays, you could use arrays with unnest:

```
select * from unnest(ARRAY[1, 2, 3]::int[], ARRAY[4, 5, 6]::int[]) as v(lon, lat);
 lon | lat
-----+-----
   1 |   4
   2 |   5
   3 |   6
(3 rows)

select * from unnest(ARRAY[]::int[], ARRAY[]::int[]) as v(lon, lat);
 lon | lat
-----+-----
(0 rows)
```

You'll have to cast the arrays to the appropriate type (probably not int[]).  Postgres will guess the type if the arrays aren't empty, but it will throw an error if they are empty and you don't cast them to a specific type.